# PHP simple html dom pass url issue

Tags: php, angularjs, url, simple-html-dom

Here's my problem: I'm trying to pass a URL in the form of a string through angular to PHP, like so:

```
 $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "contentParser.php",
        data: {
            data: "http://www.google.com"
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
        $log.log(response);
        this.article = response;
    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

This string reaches PHP fine, however if I try to use load_file with that string like so:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $html->load_file($data->data);
    echo $html;
?>
```

,I get the following error over the "echo $html" line:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function innertext() on null in

Which would make it seem as if the string isn't correct. Now, if I encode the url like so:

```
$url = urlencode($data->data);
```

and add that to load_file, I receive this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

I have tried:
adding AllowEncodedSlashes On/NoDecode,
replacing %3A with : and %2F with / (perhaps I did it wrong?)

Honestly, I'm at my wit's end. Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: For start, AFAIK google is using SSL, so it would be `https`

Comment: I'm guessing the error messages points to a file and line that you didn't post. Can you update your question to include the line of code (and a few lines prior to that) that actually cause the error? You're probably calling `innertext()` on the result of some other function call that's failing.

Comment: Edited the question and added the PHP code

Comment: For everyone else that have this problem, I found a workaround:
instead of using `$html= new simple_html_dom(); $html->load_file()`, using `$html=file_get_html('url')` seems to do the trick. Not quite sure what this is about, maybe someone smarter can explain?